# How do Apache Ignite async methods ACTUALLY work?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, ignite

My question is Apache Ignite has the putAsync() method now how is it actually enqueuing my data? Is it going into memory? Is it going into a log on disk? How does my data actually go into the database from the future once it's complete?

Kafka for example when you want to send data you call producer.send() which is async and I believe Kafka is enqueuing your request into a buffer which a background thread is flushing over the network. If that buffer exceeds a limit then it will throw back an exception.

So for Kafka I know there's another thread flushing the data in the background & there is a limit to how many async calls I could make based on the buffer size.

I am looking for a similar explanation for Ignite!

Answer (score 0):

You may have just one async call in background per thread. The second async call will actually be synchronous if the first one is not completed yet.

Async call may also be synchronous when it is called on the server node which is primary for a given key/partition.  Otherwise, a network request is sent to primary node and the control is returned to your code.

Comment: Is it possible to increase the number of async calls in one go?

Comment: In general, no. But you can use more threads or use Data Streamer which is much more async. You can also use getAll/putAll or SQL.